# How to make relation between enumtype and itemtype in Hybris

Tags: one-to-many, enumeration, sap-commerce-cloud, relation

I have an enumtype :

```
<items>
 <enumtypes>
  <enumtype code="FuelEnumeration" generate="true" autocreate="true" dynamic="true"> 
   <value code="diesel"></value>
   <value code="gasoline"></value> 
   <value code="ethanol"></value>
 </enumtype> 
</enumtypes>
```

Here is the itemtype :

```
<itemtypes> 
<itemtype code="Car" extends="Product" autocreate="true" generate="true">
 <attributes> ... <attribute qualifier="fuel" type="FuelEnumeration"> 
<description>Fuel for this car</description> 
<persistence type="property"></persistence>
 </attribute>
```

I want to create a One to Many relation between enumtype and itemtype so that one car can have many FuelEnumeration, How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanted to do one-to-many using relation, below is how you do it.

```
    <relation code="Car2FuelRel" generate="true" localized="false" autocreate="true">
        <sourceElement qualifier="car" type="Car" cardinality="one">
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true" />
        </sourceElement>
        <targetElement qualifier="fuel" type="FuelEnumeration" cardinality="many" collectiontype="set">
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true" />
        </targetElement>
    </relation>
```

However, this is incorrect, because one-to-many means that a Car can have many fuel enum, but a fuel enum can belong to only one car. It's probably better to do to this as many-to-many. Just change the cardinality of sourceElement to `many`.

Optionally, you can also use a collection as Raushan described. However, collection makes it difficult to search if a Car has a certain fuel value. Hybris recommends to use relations, instead of collections.

SEE:

- Relations: https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/bae7ed9732a4423f867114217ae21b46.html

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please create Collection type

```
<collectiontype code="fuelEnumColl"
        elementtype="FuelEnumeration" autocreate="true" generate="true"
        type="list" />
```

Then refer to your item type.

```
<attribute qualifier="fuel" type="fuelEnumColl">
```